# Print 123454321 without if statements and using only 2 variables

Tags: popularity-contest, restricted-source

The challenge: Write a function, that delivers following output: "1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1".

Kids stuff? Of course. But here's the point:

- You only can use: 1 for loop, 2 int variables.
- You must not use: IF terms, another function, ...
- Do not hardcode the output

There are also some more restrictions to make this harder:

- No functions like abs or sth. else are allowed! (Yep, it's possible)
- No static output like echo "1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1"

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the most votes wins!

Comment: I think the function you're looking for is `abs`. Python: `for i in range(1, 10): print 5-abs(5-i),`

Comment: Just to give folks some background this was a "do my homework" question on SO 10 min ago...

Comment: @monocell Most of the languages he gets answers in will be too obscure to be useful.. let alone readable.

Comment: So easy: `print "1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1"`

Comment: @Mhmd: That answer fails the stipulation "do not hard code the output"

Comment: @monocell it was / is a facebook challenge.. Not my homework ;)

Comment: I think `6-%:*:_5+i.11` (J) is technically valid, but I won't post it, for the silly amount of rules it breaks/bends.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks too much like a homework assignment or "brain twister".

Comment: Fun fact! If you take the binary representation of the unicode string "1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1" and convert it into a base 10 number, it becomes 3922771099780750640552066885681. I wanted to generate this in some epic way and cout it with No Comment's `@` operator, but turns out, **it's prime**. What.

Comment: @Trimsty what if you append a newline?

Comment: @JanDvorak 62764337596492010248833070170906, which is not prime: `2 * 3 * 9587 * 911979101447 * 1196448709617859`. :c

Comment: `for(x=11111;x<=11111;x*=x);printf("%d\n", x);`

Comment: I don't understand why OP's accepted answer is as is, as it doesn't comply with the rules.

Comment: Even if it's a 'solve my homework' type of question, the question is interesting and some creative answers can be given. Why do we need to judge intentions/purpose while the problem set is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cobra

### Really, this is quite trivial.

```cobra
class Program
    def main
        for i in 10, Console.write(5 - Math.abs(5 - i))
```

Or

```cobra
class Program
    def main
        v as int = 123454321
        for i in v.toString, Console.write(i)
```

Or even simpler

```cobra
class Program
    def main
        print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

### But if you insist on following the question *exactly*:

```cobra
class Program
    def main
        num as int = 123454321
        for i in '[num]'
            Console.write(i)
            Console.write(' ')
```

This uses only one integer variable, only one loop, and the only function explicitly called is used for output.

Comment: I'm not sure whether `Math.abs` constitutes "another function" which is forbidden. haha

Comment: I was about to submit your latest example to lol

Comment: @justhalf latest version only explicitly calls the print function.

Comment: The last 3 versions appear to fail the stipulation "do not hardcode the output"

Comment: Doesn't seem particularly right, since these solutions either use hard-coded data or use another function (Math.abs).

Answer (score 10):

### Python

One for loop, one int variable (`i`), no if, no other functions (unless you consider `print` or `+-*/` as functions, haha):

```
for i in range(9):
    print i+1 - 2*(i//5)*(i-4),
```

Comment: This one gets my vote as it complies with ALL the rules, i.e. does not use any functions or extra variables. I think we can call print a procedure as we are not interested in its return value (I don't know if it returns a value in Python.) `//` is integer division in python? hmmm

Comment: Steveverrill,  '//' one of the slashes is likely a directive for the print function to ignore the other slash.  I think the idea here is that print functions will think the slash is a file system slash instead of a math operator.  The double slash clears this up.

Comment: @Marc `//` is integer divison in python. You're thinking of `\\\`, where one backslash escapes the other.

Comment: @steve Integer division is the default in python 2, in python 3 you specify it manually with `//`.

Comment: I'm working with Python 2 and Python 3 sometimes, so to be sure that I'm doing integer division, I always use `//`, because it works in both Python 2 and Python 3.
Thanks for all the votes!

Answer (score 5):

## C

No function, no hidden IF (abs, min, etc.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
int sum=0;
for (int i=3; i<12; i++)
    {
    sum += 1-2*(i/8);
    printf("%d\n", sum );
    }
}
```

Explanation : 
The 4th bit of i is the heart of the trick : it's 0 for [3,7] and 1 for [8,11].

i/8 gives the value of the bit (just like i>>3) for i in [3,11] it gives : 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1

1-2*(i/8) is simple math to obtain 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1

+= is used to sum the values

Comment: This is another answer that fully complies with all the rules. I was thinking on something like this, but at the end I used another approach since why two int variables when you can only use one? :D

Comment: Why hopping when you can use your both legs? :o) But I have to admit that your answer is better.

Comment: I like your analogy. +1

Answer (score 4):

**Javascript, 32 characters**

```
+new Date(1970,0,2,11,17,34,321)
```

*edit:*
**not timezone-dependant, 42 chars**

```
+new Date(Date.UTC(1970,0,2,10,17,34,321))
```

Comment: I get `107254321` http://jsfiddle.net/KnLJL/

Comment: what browser are you using? it works for me in firefox and chrome.

Comment: Firefox 24.3.0.

Comment: sorry, dunno. works with firefox 29.

Comment: Chrome 35, I get `145054321`.

Comment: This answer is probably timezone-dependent.

Comment: and hard-coded.

Comment: of course... to make it timezone-independent, it'd have to be `+new Date(Date.UTC(1970,0,2,10,17,34,321))`

Comment: Please add that to your answer

Answer (score 3):

## Delphi XE3

I dont think this requires much explaining right?

```
function p:string;
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for I:=1 to 4 do
    Result:=Format('%s%d ',[Result,I]);
  Result:=Format('%s%d%s',[Result,5,ReverseString(Result)]);
end;
```

In case it does.
Function loops from 1 to 4, and keeps adding the number + [space].
Then it adds I again which became 5 which made it quit the loop and adds the reversed string as it is now.

## Variation

```
function p:string;
```

const
      s='123454321'
    var
      i:integer;
    begin
      s:='123454321';
      for I:=1to Length(s) do
        Result:=Format('%s %s',[Result,s[i]]);
      Exit(Trim(Result));
    end;
This might seem hardcoded but the constant doesnt have the spaces that are required.
Although it might seem impossible but there is a solution that is even lamer than this.

```
function p:string;
const
  s='123454321'
begin
  result:=Format('%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s',[s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5],s[6],s[7],s[8],s[9]])  
  {or}  
  result:=Format('%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s',[s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5],s[4],s[3],s[2],s[1]])
 {OR!}  
  result:=Format('%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d',[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])
end;
```

Comment: I would argue that to reverse a string you require another loop. But let OP decide on this.

Comment: hmm.. Fair point sir. But yes let the OP decide and hope he agrees with it :P ill see if I can come up with something else.

Answer (score 3):

#### Golfscript, 16 characters

```
6,(;)1$-1%++' '*
```

I assume this is meant to be a code golf?

No variables. All data (two arrays and a number) is on the stack. The only loops are implicit ones.

Online demonstration: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=NiwoOykxJC0xJSsrJyAnKg%3D%3D

Answer (score 3):

**C++: Works finely in VC 11.0**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool called = false;
int main();
int f() {
    called = true;
    typedef vector<int>::iterator _v_interate;
    int l;
    static bool d;
    vector<int> iVector;
    for(l = 1; (true); (!d) ? l++ : l--) {
        _v_interate i = find(iVector.begin(), iVector.end(), 4);
        _v_interate i2 = find(iVector.begin(), iVector.end(), 3);
        _v_interate i3 = find(iVector.begin(), iVector.end(), 2);
        _v_interate i4 = find(iVector.begin(), iVector.end(), 1);
        _v_interate i5 = find(iVector.begin(), iVector.end(), 5);
        d =  (i != iVector.end()) &&  (i2 != iVector.end()) &&  (i3 != iVector.end()) &&  (i4 != iVector.end()) ? 1 : 0;
        iVector.push_back(l);
        cout << l << " ";
        (d && (l==1) ? main() : 0);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    !called ? f() : 0;
    _getch();
    exit(0); // Removing the exit(0) causes an infinite loop; I don't know why.
    return 0;
}
```

A simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>

void main() {
  cout << "1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken on the count, but I count 10 variables in your first solution which is about 5x more than the maximum. And your second solution fails the "do not hardcode the output" stipulation.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl

#### Version 1:

```
for(1..9){
    $x = ($_%18 - 5);
    print 5 - ($x, -$x)[$x < -$x] . " ";
}
```

#### Version 2:

```
for(1..9){
    $x = ($_%18 - 5);
    $x =~ s/-//;
    print 5 - $x . " ";
}
```

For both versions: 1 For loop, and 2 variables, `$_` and `$x`, and I'm not using `if` or any other function.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby - **47 chars**

```
(1..4).to_a.push((1..5).to_a.reverse).join ' '
```

Edit - **33 chars**

```
[*(1..4),[*(1..5)].reverse]*' '
```

Comment: `to_a` can be simplified using splats since Ruby 1.9.x or so. Also, look up `Array#*`

Comment: @JanDvorak Made it 33 chars

Answer (score 2):

**Java**

Used one loop and the loop variable. Added a constant for the upper bound.

```
public class Test {
   private static final int BOUND = 5;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i = 1; i < BOUND * 2; i++) {
         System.out.print(i - (2 * ((i % BOUND) * (i / BOUND))) + " ");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 83

```
+++++++[>+++++++>+++++++>+++++++>+++++++>+++++++<<<<<-]>.>+.>++.>+++.>++++.<.<.<.<.
```

Only 1 loop, no `if`s (if you don't count the loop as an `if`). No `int` variables.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript

```
function f(){
  for ( var i=1,j=5; j>0; ++i>j&&(--i,--i,--j) )
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: `for(a=b=0;b++<9;)console.log(a+=(b<6)-(b>5))`

Comment: How does this work? `++i>j&&(--i,--i,--j)`

Answer (score 2):

## C

Not sure if it follows exactly the rules but my answer is below

```c
int main()
{
    int x;
    for(x = 123454321; x > 10; x /= 10)
    {
        printf("%d ", x % 10);
    }
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

[Run the code](https://ideone.com/lJuyk1)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess the fastest and most naive solution (in Python) would be:

```
' '.join (str(x) for x in range(1,6)) + ' ' + ' '.join (str(x) for x in range(4,0,-1))
```

Comment: Two `range` will constitute as two loops, which is against the rule, I guess.

Comment: @justhalf I was rather relying on range not counting as a loop :p

Comment: And by the way the fastest solution in Python should be `print '1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1'` :D

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

This might not be the best and fastest way to do it, but I like what I came up with.

```
z = '';
for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) { // Don't need a loop, but hey, I like loops!
    z += x + ' '; // Creates "1 2 3 4 5 "
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = z + z.split("").reverse().join("").substring(2, 10); 
// "1 2 3 4 5 " + " 4 3 2 1"
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

You can see it in action [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebWaL/4/)!

Comment: Uses the function `String.prototype.reverse`

Answer (score 1):

As 2.0

```
var num:Int = 11111;
alert(num*num);
```

Answer (score 1):

**C**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 21911761; i > 0 && printf("%d", i&7); i = i>>3)
        i > 1 && printf(" ");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 79 chars (standalone: 131 chars)

```
int b=-1,i=1;for(;i>0&(i<5||(b=1)==1);i-=b){System.out.print(i+(b==i?"":" "));}
```

Uses two `int`s, and no other variables. No if statements, just a for loop for evaluation. This will run on its own when put in the main(String[] args) method in a class, or in any other function. The full code, including class declaration and method, is 131 chars.

```
public class M{public static void main(String[]a){int b=-1,i=1;for(;i>0&(i<5||(b=1)==1);i-=b){System.out.print(i+(b==i?"":" "));}}}
```

While I'm at it:

### PHP, 70 chars (standalone: 78 chars)

```
$b=-1;for($i=1;$i>0&($i<5||($b=1)==1);$i-=$b){echo$i.($b==$i?"":" ");}
```

Uses same method as Java. Standalone script is 62 chars:

```
<?php $b=-1;for($i=1;$i>0&($i<5||($b=1)==1);$i-=$b){echo$i.($b==$i?"":" ");}?>
```

Comment: I think that the ternary operator would count as an if statement

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran 90: 60

```
integer::j(9)=5;do i=1,4;j(i)=i;j(10-i)=i;enddo;print*,j;end
```

If you wanted it formatted slightly better, I can add a few characters to make the print statement `print'(9i2)',j`. Ungolfed & written properly, this is

```
program main
   implicit none
   integer :: i, j(9)
   j = 5
   do i=1,4
      j(i) = i
      j(10-i) = i
   enddo
   print *,j
end program main
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell

```
((1..9)|%{
    $_ = ($_%18-5)
5 - @($_,-$_)[$_ -lt -$_]
})-join ' '
```

1 variable, no `if`, no functions (unless you were to count `-join` which is just for displaying the data...

**Explanation:** Loops from 1 to 9, then for each value calculates the reminder of the current value by 18, then subtracts 5 and assigns it to the currently used `$_` variable. After that it evaluates `$_ < -$_` (this is to handle negative values), and uses the result (`False`/`True`) to get the value from the array `@($_,-$_)`, therefore making sure we always get a positive number in this case, after that it subtracts this number to 5 and finally joins the results with space.

Comment: Since I can't add an answer, another option would be `"$(1..5+4..1)"`

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 53

```
(4 to 12).foldLeft(1)((a,b)=>{print(a);a+1-2*(b/8)})
```

I stole the neat bit shifting idea from @cpri

http://scalafiddle.net/console/3b3fff6463464959dcd1b68d0320f781

Comment: This fits the rules better:
(1 to 9).map(x => 5-Math.abs(5-x)).mkString(" ")

Comment: If you found a shorter code, you can [edit] your answer to update the code.